# How many chain links do I need for my chain

Tags: chain

I have a 2017 DaVinci Django mountain bike and I am planning to upgrade my cassette to a 11/46 from 11/42. I would like to buy a new KMC chain. How may links do I need?114 or 116? Maybe it’s a different number. Can you help?

Comment: You would need 2-3 more links than the old chain.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0YibMDWBAw

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks, my understanding was if you have an 8 speed cassette then you use an 8 speed chain, wouldn't the variation in length be taken up with the cage?

Comment: @DanK -- The cage will be able to "adapt" to a difference of 2-4 links, usually.  Depends on the specifics of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would buy a chain that is "long enough" and then shorten it to the correct length. If you're adding 4 extra teeth, then presumably you would need at least 2 extra links from what you currently have. Look at [Sheldon Brown's chain length](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html#chain) article for determining the correct length.

> The best technique for setting chain length is to thread the chain onto the large/large combination, without running it through the rear derailer. Mesh the two ends on to the large chainwheel so that one complete link (one inch, -- one inner and one outer half-link) overlaps. In almost all cases, this will give the optimum length.